# Terminology for written "CW-like" Code?

Tags: morse-code

Morse Code is defined by most dictionaries in terms of sequences of short and long signals.  What would be the most common or most descriptive terminology for un-timed written or printed code, where the encodings are not longer or shorter?  (I would like to differentiate this written form from actual CW, as calling both Morse Code could be confusing in some situations, such as when describing good/bad methods of transcription.)

Examples of written code include encoding using UTF8 or ASCII 45 and 46 (both 1 character in length), or using the two phonetic terms "dit" and "dah" (both 3 characters in length).

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps name it a *transcription* or *written representation*, or something similar. Maybe it has a specific name (e.g., related to the paper tapes where Morse code was transcribed in the early days of telegraphy), but I failed to find it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[digital](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digital) code* might be an appropriate term?

> **digital** (not comparable)
>
> 1. Having to do with digits (fingers or toes); performed with a finger.
> 2. Property of representing values as discrete numbers rather than a continuous spectrum.
> 3. Of or relating to computers or the Information Age.

This neatly encompasses an allusion to actual CW which is traditionally performed by moving your finger.